# Retrieve ID from the Invoice Date URL

Tags: netsuite

I want to retrieve the URL from the Date link and get the ID in the URL from the Invoice.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyYcV.png)

Answer (score 0):

The ID in the URL is the internal ID.  That's as simple as getting the record ID.  The billable time URL should always start with "/app/accounting/transactions/timebill.nl" followed by ?id=, and then the internal ID of that particular time entry.  The billable time sublist is the time sublist.  I've added a few links below, for information.  Not sure if you are trying to write code for this, or what (the question does not specify that).

If you are looking for specific scripting assistance, update your post with the script that you currently have, and where you are running into errors.

- [Records Browser: Invoice](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2019_2/script/record/invoice.html)
- [SuiteScript 2.0 API Reference](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=book_4563537302.html)
- [Record.getSublist(options)](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4599715398.html)
- [Record.getSublistValue(options)](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4273166148.html)